# Raise contents of numbered equation with respect to its tag

Tags: equations, amsmath, vertical-spacing

In the following situation:

```
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla:
\begin{equation}
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1&c_1&d_1&f_1&g_1&h_1&i_1&j_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2&d_2&f_2&g_2&h_2&i_2&j_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3&d_3&f_3&g_3&h_3&i_3&j_3\\
a_4&b_4&c_4&d_4&f_4&g_4&h_4&i_4&j_4\\
a_5&b_5&c_5&d_5&f_5&g_5&h_5&i_5&j_5\\
a_6&b_6&c_6&d_6&f_6&g_6&h_6&i_6&j_6\\
a_7&b_7&c_7&d_7&f_7&g_7&h_7&i_7&j_7\\
a_8&b_8&c_8&d_8&f_8&g_8&h_8&i_8&j_8\\
a_9&b_9&c_9&d_9&f_9&g_9&h_9&i_9&j_9\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
```

[image]

where I have used a very low `\belowdisplayskip` to better illustrate the problem, I would like to raise the formula with respect to the tag “(1)” since there is a lot of vertical space on the left part, so that the label can easily be absorbed, and a line can be gained.

The problem is I don't know where to place a command for raising the formula contents. I tried with a `\raisebox` but nothing happened. And inserting a `\vspace*{-12pt}` inside the formula indeed removed one line, but… under the formula, not above it.

Any suggestion on how act on the vertical space between label and formula?

Comment: Of course there is the nasty solution, unworthy of any decent TeXist, that consists in using first an empty `equation` environnement only to obtain the label, then a negative vertical kern and finally an unnumbered formula, but I was wondering whether you had a *real* solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `gather` you could use `\raisetag` (although it does warn a bit about overfull boxes)

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla:
\begin{gather}
\raisetag{-2em}
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1&c_1&d_1&f_1&g_1&h_1&i_1&j_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2&d_2&f_2&g_2&h_2&i_2&j_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3&d_3&f_3&g_3&h_3&i_3&j_3\\
a_4&b_4&c_4&d_4&f_4&g_4&h_4&i_4&j_4\\
a_5&b_5&c_5&d_5&f_5&g_5&h_5&i_5&j_5\\
a_6&b_6&c_6&d_6&f_6&g_6&h_6&i_6&j_6\\
a_7&b_7&c_7&d_7&f_7&g_7&h_7&i_7&j_7\\
a_8&b_8&c_8&d_8&f_8&g_8&h_8&i_8&j_8\\
a_9&b_9&c_9&d_9&f_9&g_9&h_9&i_9&j_9\end{pmatrix},
\end{gather}
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

enter image description here
\end{document}
```

You could avoid being overfull by reducing `\arraycolsep`, if you reduce it enough you could go back to `equation`

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla:
\begin{equation}
\setlength\arraycolsep{4.5pt}
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1&c_1&d_1&f_1&g_1&h_1&i_1&j_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2&d_2&f_2&g_2&h_2&i_2&j_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3&d_3&f_3&g_3&h_3&i_3&j_3\\
a_4&b_4&c_4&d_4&f_4&g_4&h_4&i_4&j_4\\
a_5&b_5&c_5&d_5&f_5&g_5&h_5&i_5&j_5\\
a_6&b_6&c_6&d_6&f_6&g_6&h_6&i_6&j_6\\
a_7&b_7&c_7&d_7&f_7&g_7&h_7&i_7&j_7\\
a_8&b_8&c_8&d_8&f_8&g_8&h_8&i_8&j_8\\
a_9&b_9&c_9&d_9&f_9&g_9&h_9&i_9&j_9\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.

enter image description here
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\raisetag`works indeed, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You might use the `medsize`environment for the matrix (~80% of  displaystyle) to obtain a normal placement of the tag:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}



\usepackage{amsmath} 
  \usepackage{nccmath} 
  \begin{document}

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla:
\begin{equation}
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e)=\begin{medsize}\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1&c_1&d_1&f_1&g_1&h_1&i_1&j_1\\
a_2&b_2&c_2&d_2&f_2&g_2&h_2&i_2&j_2\\
a_3&b_3&c_3&d_3&f_3&g_3&h_3&i_3&j_3\\
a_4&b_4&c_4&d_4&f_4&g_4&h_4&i_4&j_4\\
a_5&b_5&c_5&d_5&f_5&g_5&h_5&i_5&j_5\\
a_6&b_6&c_6&d_6&f_6&g_6&h_6&i_6&j_6\\
a_7&b_7&c_7&d_7&f_7&g_7&h_7&i_7&j_7\\
a_8&b_8&c_8&d_8&f_8&g_8&h_8&i_8&j_8\\
a_9&b_9&c_9&d_9&f_9&g_9&h_9&i_9&j_9\end{pmatrix}\end{medsize},
\end{equation}
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the matrix is there only to illustrate the problem, in reality the right part is not scalable…

Comment: @yannis: in this case, the simplest solution would be to load `geometry` to have more decent margins. Other possibility: split your real equation